# PHP Set and Read a Cookie String

Tags: php, cookies

I've got my form all completed, I know how to set a singular cookie using PHP however what is the best format to set a cookie string. I would like to have a cookie like so (or similar, my formatting is just an example);

Prefs[theme=this&layout=that]

How would I set a cookie like so and then get the information from my string?

### Code So Far:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        $a = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s");
        $b = "Cookies=true&Cookies_Accepted=" . $a . "";
        $c = $_POST["APT_SELECTED"];
        $d = $_POST["APPT_SELECTED"];
        if ($d == 'Custom') {
            $d = $c;
        };
        $e = $_POST["APL_SELECTED"];
        $f = $_POST["APTNP_SELECTED"];
        $g = $_POST["APSNP_SELECTED"];
        $h = $_POST["APSNM_SELECTED"];
        $i = $_POST["ScreenTimeout"];
        $j = time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        $k = "/admin/";
        $l = "rafflebananza.com";
        $m = array(
            'APCA' => 'true',
            'APCAW' => $a,
            'APT' => $c,
            'APPT' => $d,
            'APL' => $e,
            'APTNP' => $f,
            'APSNP' => $g,
            'APSNM' => $h,
            'APLSA' => $i
        );
        foreach ($m as $n => $o) {
            setcookie("RBAP_Prefs[$n]", $o, $j, $k, $l);
        };
        header("Location: http://admin.rafflebananza.com/incex.php");
    };
?>
```

Comment: You know you can call `setcookie` multiple times, one for each value you want to set, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP will allow you to set string values using `[]` notation in `setcookie()`, You may make multiple calls to `setcookie()` with your two sub-keys, and `Prefs` as the name.

Technically, PHP will set multiple cookies for array elements, but when read back from `$_COOKIE`, PHP will arrange it exactly as you would expect to read the array.

So you may set it as:

```
// And set each in the cookie 'Prefs'
setcookie('Prefs[theme]', 'this' /*, $timeout, $path, $domain... */);
setcookie('Prefs[layout]', 'that' /*, $timeout, $path, $domain... */);
```

And it will be readable as an array in `$_COOKIE['Prefs']`

```
print_r($_COOKIE['Prefs']);
// Array (
//   [theme] => this,
//   [layout] => that
// )
```

Rather than manually calling `setcookie()` for each one, you may loop over an existing array. This is handy if you have only one level of nesting.

```
// Define your array
$prefs = array('theme' => 'this', 'layout' => 'that');
// Loop to create keys
foreach ($prefs as $key => $value) {
  setcookie("Prefs[$key]", $value, $timeout, $path, $domain);
}
```

If for some reason you *must* begin with a query-string style `&` delimited string like `theme=this&layout=that`, you may first parse it into an array [using `parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
parse_str('theme=this&layout=that', $prefs);
// $prefs is now as in the previous example. Proceed to set
// cookie values with the foreach loop...
```

If you decide you would like to store the cookie in the string format, you may pass that string into `setcookie()` and then use `parse_str()` to read it back out of `$_COOKIE`.  I don't like this method though, I would rather see the cookie set as array values above.

```
// Set it as a string
setcookie('Prefs', 'theme=this&layout=that');
// And parse it from $_COOKIE into $prefs
parse_str($_COOKIE['Prefs'], $prefs);
```

[More examples are available](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) in the `setcookie()` documentation.

Comment: Just configuring my array, getting all the values. I'll comment with some real feedback soon @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @TimMarshall See also the addition about `parse_str()` if you want to stick with your string format as the originating format, but still store them as an array.

Comment: I have no SSL at the moment so the last option seems best as I'm limited to two cookies. I'm still getting this ready and once I'm done I'll edit question with my code @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: updated question with my PHP code. Do i need to set `$timeout, $path, $domain`?

Comment: @TimMarshall Depends on your application. Look at the `setcookie()` docs for info about those. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php Leaving out timeout makes it valid for the session, so if you need the cookie to persist into the far future you must set the timeout. Setting path to `/` is probably needed for prefs because otherwise the cookie would only be valid on the _page_ it was set on rather than your whole site. Domain only needs to be set if you have to share the cookie across subdomains.

Comment: @TimMarshall It's in `$_COOKIE` as a 2D array, so for example `echo $_COOKIE['RBAP_Prefs']['APSNM']`

Comment: @TimMarshall Are you all sorted out on this one too? I can chat if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69845/discussion-between-tim-marshall-and-michael-berkowski).

Comment: Yes please, my cookie is not setting