# PHP get multiple values from cookie

Tags: php

I am storing a cookie with multiple values from an asp.net page (VB). I am then trying to retrieve the values from the cookie in PHP and can't find a way to get the multiple values using PHP

`$myRole` is only returning "R" not "admin"

php full cookie `var_dump($myCookie);` is `string(48) "Role=admin&User=myuser&Time=3/8/2017 8:08:43 PM"`

ASP.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
     Dim cookie As HttpCookie
    cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("PHPAUTH")

    If (cookie Is Nothing) Then
        sb.Append("Cookie was not received from the client. ")
        sb.Append("Creating cookie to add to the response. <br/>")
        cookie = New HttpCookie("PHPAUTH")


        If Not Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "admin") Then
            'cookie.Values("Role") = "not in role"
        Else
            cookie.Values("Role") = "admin"
            cookie.Values("User") = User.Identity.Name
        End If 

        cookie.Values("Time") = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10D)
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
    Else
        sb.Append("Cookie retrieved from client. <br/>")
        sb.Append("Cookie Name: " + cookie.Name + "<br/>")
        sb.Append("Cookie User: " + cookie.Values("User") + "<br/>")
        sb.Append("Cookie Role: " + cookie.Values("Role") + "<br/>")
        sb.Append("Cookie Time: " + cookie.Values("Time") + "<br/>")
        sb.Append("Cookie Expiration Date: " & _
            cookie.Expires.ToString() & "<br/>")
    End If

    Label1.Text = sb.ToString()

End Sub
```

PHP:

```
$myCookie = $_COOKIE["PHPAUTH"];
$myRole = $myCookie["Role"];
var_dump($myCookie);
var_dump($myRole);
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_COOKIE["PHPAUTH"]);` return? If it's empty, your cookie isn't getting set.

Comment: what is the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_COOKIE);` at php end?

Comment: the output is in my question `$myCookie`

Answer (score 0):

seems the cookie string needs to be parsed into an array:

[PHP Set and Read a Cookie String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220280/php-set-and-read-a-cookie-string)

my solution was:

```
$myCookie = $_COOKIE["PHPAUTH"];
parse_str($myCookie, $prefs);
var_dump($prefs);
echo print_r($prefs['Role']);
```